# How do I completely disable shadows on xfce panel indicators and applications? (Xubuntu 16.04 and compton)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, compton

I've recently upgraded from Xubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 and I've noticed that some windows have shadows and some don't (I don't want them). I'm using compton as my compositor with the following shadow related settings in my ~/.compton.conf:

```
shadow = false;
no-dnd-shadow = true;
no-dock-shadow = true;
clear-shadow = true;
shadow-radius = 1;
shadow-offset-x = -1;
shadow-offset-y = -1;
shadow-opacity = 0.1;
```

I assume `shadow = false;` is enough to disable them, the other settings are there as part of my trial and error to see if I could affect the remaining shadows.

The shadows that remain look like this:
[image: Shadows on indicator plugin]

They also appear on the Skype and networking context menus, but not on any of the others, including the calendar and user switcher.

In addition to the panel, I'm also getting a shadow on the calculator application, but not on any others that I have tested…

Are these being rendered by compton, or is there something else going on here? If I kill compton, those shadows are replaced with a big block of black, as seen here on the calculator, but this also happens with the indicators in my panel, too:

[image: With and without compton running]

Answer (score 10):

## For default Xfce compositor

Go to `Settings` -> `Windows Manager Tweaks`. Choose the tab `Compositor` and uncheck the option `Show shadow under regular windows`.

## For `compton` compositor

Add the following lines to `wintypes` setting in `~/.config/compton.conf`

```
dropdown_menu = { shadow = false; };
popup_menu    = { shadow = false; };
```

Example:

```
wintypes:
{
    ## To disable shadows for menus
    # menu        = { shadow = false; };
    dropdown_menu = { shadow = false; };
    popup_menu    = { shadow = false; };
    # utility     = { shadow = false; };
};
```

Hope you success!

An example for `compton.conf` in [git.archlinux.org](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/compton.conf?h=packages/compton#n80)

Comment: I believe this interface is for configuring the default xfce compositor; I have "Enable display compositing" un-ticked here (but "Show shadows under regular windows" is disabled, anyway).